# js geolocation but without prompting - possible?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, navigator

Is it possible to get the geolocation of a user without the browser prompt?

[Here's the code sample from W3](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)

```
<script>
   var x = document.getElementById("demo")

   function getLocation(){
     if(navigator.geolocation){
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
     } else {
       x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
     }
     function showPosition(position){
       x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
       "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;   
     }
</script>
```

Is there any `preventPrompt()`-like function ?

Comment: *"the reason is, i am using the lat and longt to give of user, to give the user very important information about what the user is looking for."* ... isn't this always the case when you want to use the user's location? ;)

Comment: @FelixKling, yeah, you are right? :D

Comment: im very glad that my browser prevents people like you from disregarding my response to the prompt.

Comment: @iputonmyrobeanwizardhat, my plan is good plan, dont worry

Comment: you can try using 3rd party geo location API, like our https://ip-api.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cant prevent the prompt, its a security feature cause not every user wanna share its location.

From the [W3C docs](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#security):

> A conforming implementation of this specification must provide a
>   mechanism that protects the user's privacy and this mechanism should
>   ensure that no location information is made available through this API
>   without the user's express permission.

But you can try to use a service like [geoip](http://www.geoiptool.com/) in the error callback.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Cause all implementations will have such a prompt. But you can try using geoIp or other services in the error callback

Comment: bytheway: can i then customize the prompt message so that i can tell the user that confirming the prompt is important. ?

Comment: It dont think you can style the prompt, cause its like an alert. But you can open an modal overlay in the error callback.

Comment: okay, nonsense, otherwise hackers can custom the message and use users location for bad purposes..

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.

The prompt is there so that the user can choose whether you know the location or not.