# using force geolocation in php at my site

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm trying to apply this example at my site 
[here example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)

i try to use nearest places to user who log in to my site

i need to get longitude  an latitude value when page load .. don't ask me if you want to allow or deny

and how can i use this code with php

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To, answer it no. it's a browser developer thing that you cannot control

you are probably looking or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538883/js-geolocation-but-without-prompting-possible)