# Acces mobile GPS data from web site

Tags: javascript, mobile, web, gps, geolocation

Can I access the GPS of a mobile from browser but without the user authorization?
I am using the html5 Geolocation navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition but this needs the user confirmation.
Could I access the current user position using javascript but without asking to the authorization user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [js geolocation but without prompting - possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538883/js-geolocation-but-without-prompting-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, never.** Nor should you even try. That would lead to a huge lack of trust between you and your users. Tracking a user without the user's consent would be a huge invasion of privacy. Feel free to read up on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) to learn more.