# How to Know Geolocation of Client who are using my web application?

Tags: html, geolocation

I have one web application. I have to know the Geolocation(Longitude & Latitude) of Clients who are using my web application? As per my understanding, I can do it using Html5 Geolocation Apis. But the problem in this scenario is this that it requires client permission. So is there any way I can do it without client permission?

Please let me know if my understanding is wrong about Html5 Geolocation Apis.

Thanks,
Gopal Lal

Answer (score 1):

I have copied this answer from [Michael C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1941686/michael-c) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017854/geolocation-without-requesting-permission).

"Based on http://www.geolocation.com, there is another way to determine the geolocation other than HTML5.

You can load a local database to query geolocation by IP address. No user intervene required because the web server can retrieve the IP address in every connection.

If you are looking for ZIP code information, then there is at least one vendor available immediately in the market. You can visit http://www.ip2location.com (DB9)."

Answer (score 1):

Have you  tried the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)? Its pretty much useful and accurate as well.
Also, you can use the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) for the same purpose. Refer to an example [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Maps-API-V3-Get-Latitude-and-Longitude-of-a-location-from-Address-using-JavaScript.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand 100% your question but for geo location ip tracks for web you can use Google Analytics and give you all information you need.